# Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.3

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

I updated an asp.net core 2 app with updated nuget packages.  Boom, my web app nolonger compiles.  I get the error shown below.  I tried to go in and manually change the versions by editing the csproj, but I seemed to be causing more harm than good.  Anyone have an idea how to resolve this?

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1605  Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.NETCore.App from 2.0.3 to 2.0.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
 BWD.ASPNET.Core -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet 2.0.1 -> Microsoft.NETCore.App (>= 2.0.3) 
 BWD.ASPNET.Core -> Microsoft.NETCore.App (>= 2.0.0)    BWD.ASPNET.Core E:\BWDCore\BWD.ASPNET.Core\BWD.ASPNET.Core\BWD.ASPNET.Core.csproj   1

Comment: Try to remove the package and then install it again.

Comment: alas, that didn't help.  I have uninstalled, now when I attempt to install again, I am getting a message of "blocked by project"  Ugh

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44026190/visual-studio-2017-cannot-update-microsoft-netcore-app-package-blocked-by-proj give a clue?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I had been through that question.  :-)

Comment: and I am not quite sure what is happening, but I've gone through the project, uninstalled, reinstalled at various levels and now things are compiling and running.  I can honestly say, I have no idea what fixed it.  I am guessing that it was your pointing me to the csproj and my making some weird edits.  Thanks.  :-)

Comment: well, i should say that it works, but VS is still complaining about the same error.  Interestingly, this was blocking VS from starting the project previously.  It is working now.  I have no idea why. :-/

Comment: What did work was removing the core nuget packages and then only adding back the .net core metapackages.  Thanks to my buddy Shawn Wildermuth (and everyone) for the suggestion.  :-)

Comment: Good thing you wrote about the solution. I suggest you write it down as the Answer.

Comment: There was a popular (but plagiarized) answer to this question which copied a comment from a GitHub issue. It has now been deleted, but for posterity, here is the comment: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10457#issuecomment-348365091

Answer (score 4):

What did work was removing the core nuget packages and then only adding back the .net core metapackages. Thanks to my buddy Shawn Wildermuth (and everyone) for the suggestion. :-)

I can't take credit for the answer.  I am just reposting it here for anyone that might be wondering and find this via google.  I also got some other suggestions, but none of them worked.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the links above another options is to add

```
<NoWarn>NU1605</NoWarn>
```

To element PropertyGroup

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this line in the section PropertyGroup of your *.csproj file:

```
<TargetLatestRuntimePatch>true</TargetLatestRuntimePatch>
```

Don't forget to clean the project up.

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I think Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet Version="2.0.**1**" has a dependency issue. It says it requires Microsoft.NETCore.App (>= 2.0.3).

We went back to Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet Version="2.0.**0**", and it all just worked.

Answer (score 0):

in .csproj file you can add:

```
<ItemGroup>
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.7" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference 
    Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.1" />
```