# Integration and unit tests no longer work on ASP.NET Core 2.1 failing to find assemblies at runtime

Tags: testing, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

When creating test projects or upgrading an application and tests to ASP.NET Core 2.1 / .NET Core 2.1, running tests fails with assembly load exceptions like

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.

When adding references to some other libraries there are also build warnings like

> warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.Extensions.Options" that could not be resolved.
>   warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" that could not be resolved.
>   warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions" that could not be resolved.
>   warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" that could not be resolved.
>   warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions" that could not be resolved.
>   warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features" that could not be resolved.

How can I make test projects work for testing ASP.NET Core 2.1 applications?

Comment: It seems fixed in 2.2 SDK https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/pull/2533 Test projects can  have a versionless asp.net core reference that will match the referenced project

Answer (score 74, accepted):

**Update**: This has been made easier with **2.2 Tooling**. Make sure that your `dotnet --version` SDK version is at least `2.2.100`, **even when buidling 2.1 applications**

Just add a versionless package reference to your project while keeping the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk`:

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

      <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
      </PropertyGroup>

      <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing" Version="2.1.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
        <!-- other references to xunit, test SDK etc. -->
      </ItemGroup>

      <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\AspNetCoreAppToTest\AspNetCoreAppToTest.csproj" />
      </ItemGroup>

    </Project>
```

Original:

ASP.NET Core 2.1 uses a new "shared framework" to run ASP.NET Core applications on. Test projects need to be modified/updated to also use this shared framework using one of the following approaches:

1. Change the test project's `<Project>` tag in the first line to use the web SDK (`Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` instead of `Microsoft.NET.Sdk`) and add a package reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` (or `.All` if you are using that inside the web project) **without specifying a version**

   The project file (.csproj) of the test project should now look like this:

   ```
   <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

     <PropertyGroup>
       <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
     </PropertyGroup>

     <ItemGroup>
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing" Version="2.1.1" />
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
       <!-- other references to xunit, test SDK etc. -->
     </ItemGroup>

     <ItemGroup>
       <ProjectReference Include="..\AspNetCoreAppToTest\AspNetCoreAppToTest.csproj" />
     </ItemGroup>

   </Project>
   ```
2. Alternative: Leave the `Sdk` as-is and add a `PackageReference` to the shared framework package but specify a version.

   This can be done by simply adding a NuGet reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`. However, this may cause issues since the SDK may choose to update the reference when a new patch release of the ASP.NET Core is released and the tooling is updated to reflect this. You will need update the NuGet reference for every patch release.

Comment: I was following your advice regarding the first alternative, and got the following compiler error on build. What am I doing wrong? Error CS5001 Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

Comment: That seems like a different problem because the test sdk turns the project into an executable but also emits a main method which somehow doesn't work with your project

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Well, but this seems to happen also if you start over from scratch: I've made a new asp.net core MVC web app, chose 2.1 and MVC. Then I added a new .NET core class library, replaced the project file with the above snippet and got the compile error. The result is here: https://github.com/HermannGruber/AspNetCoreAppToTest

Comment: Update: I've noticed that the compiler error disappears if we change the project output type to "class library". Or equivalently, if we add     <OutputType>Library</OutputType> to the first property group in the code snippet in your answer.

Comment: Using VS 2019, I had to also close and re-open VS + rebuild to remove the errors.

Comment: This is the only solution that will solve the issue for test projects that reference a .net core 2.1 app. THANK YOU

Comment: For ASP.NET Core 2.2 alternative 2 is enough, but got a warning about specifying a version. It works and does not give a warning without a version, i.e. just `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />`

Answer (score 12):

The question specifies ASP.NET Core 2.1, but for those running into the same problem with ASP.NET Core **2.2** it's enough to add the following to your test project file:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
```

There is [no need](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/2253#issuecomment-455823000) to set `Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web"` anymore and you should *not* add a version to the package reference above - that causes a warning.

Answer (score -2):

I was having the same problem. Add this to Test Project solved the problem

```html
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.1.1"/>
```