# What are the differences between Microsoft.NET.Sdk and Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, .net-core

I have a solution with two host projects (one is a [Web Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-2.1) and the other is a [Generic Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-2.1)) and a class library project referenced by those two host projects.

In the [Sdk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#sdk-attribute) attribute of the root tag `<Project>` of the *.csproj file, both host projects (web host and generic host) are using `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web`, but the class library project uses the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk`.

The two host projects references the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` metapackage.

The class library project are using `Microsoft.NETCore.App`, but it references some ASP.NET Core packages individually (packages of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` that are not in `Microsoft.NETCore.App`).

About the correct SDK and metapackages:

1) In the generic host project, should I use pure **.NET Core** (`Microsoft.NET.Sdk` and `Microsoft.NETCore.App`) instead of **ASP.NET Core** (`Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`) since it is not a web project?

2) In the class library project, is it fine to use `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` to avoid the possibility to reference different versions of packages that belong to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` (to avoid for example, `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App@2.1.0` in the host project and `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration@2.0.0` in the class library project)? Or I can only use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` metapackage with `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` SDK?

3) What difference does it make to use `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` or `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web`? The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#sdk-attribute) says that **"The SDK, as the layering document describes, is a set of MSBuild tasks and targets that can build .NET Core code."**, but why do we need to have both of them? In practice, what `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` does that `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` doesn't?

Comment: The web package is a subpackage of the base SDK. Anything in the regular Sdk should be available to Web applications, but not all applications made with .NET are for the web

Comment: The two comes from two different repos, and all relevant code is available, https://github.com/aspnet/websdk/blob/6b898ad0a39329ab5f0db281a9c1712e4303ed61/pack/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web.csproj and https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/ab2176b3447e3e7820b5a340408110b6d498f907/src/Tasks/Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks/Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.csproj so you might dig and see if obvious differences can be observed.

Comment: I tried to cover many aspects in my answer but since it is potentially a bit topic, I suggest following up on or moving parts out to new (and more specific) questions

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Ad (1) and (3): What are the differences between the "core" and and web SDKs, how do these affect generic host apps?

The most important differences are:

1. **Default Items**

   The web SDK has different definitions and globbing patterns for which files to include in your published application.

   E.g. when you have an `appsettings.json` file, projects using the web sdk will automatically include it since there are patterns in place that ensure that `.config`, `.json` files and all files in a `wwwroot` folder are all part of the publish output. See [the MSBuild source code on GitHub for these patterns](https://github.com/aspnet/websdk/blob/c782b82decd04b49771814064a8f9fe3a07ed341/src/ProjectSystem/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web.ProjectSystem.Targets/netstandard1.0/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web.ProjectSystem.props#L30-L32).

   If you have a generic host and don't use the Web SDK, you may need to add code to the csproj file to specify which files to copy to the publish directory (or use an IDE to change the "copy to output directory" setting which also includes files in the publish output but will also copy them to the build output):

   ```
   <ItemGroup>
     <None Update="*.json" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
   </ItemGroup>
   ```
2. **Web Publish logic**

   Another essential part of the Web SDK is that it contains the deployment logic for web applications.

   If you plan to use publish profiles (`.pubxml` files) or deploy to azure or filesystems using MSBuild / MSDeploy, you will need this publishing logic.

Ad (2): Which SDK to use for class libraries?

For maximum compatibility when publishing public libraries (e.g. via NuGet), use the core SDK and reference individual packages with the lowest possible version - e.g. 2.1.0 / 2.1.1.

If you develop a class library containing razor views, you will need to use the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor` SDK to get razor tooling (e.g. when you use the `dotnet new razorclasslib` template).

For libraries and test projects where you want to use the same meta package reference as the application, things are a bit complicated at the moment but it's going to get better:

For ASP.NET Core 2.1 tools(!) (CLI 2.1.*), I suggest using the non-web SDK for class libraries and use the version 2.1.1 of that package. Don't ever upgrade it, even if NuGet offers you an upgrade.

For test projects in 2.1 tools(!) (CLI 2.1.*), it is a bit different and tricky, see [Integration and unit tests no longer work on ASP.NET Core 2.1 failing to find assemblies at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50401152/integration-and-unit-tests-no-longer-work-on-asp-net-core-2-1-failing-to-find-as)

Beginning in 2.2 tools (CLI 2.2.100+), the version-less package references to ASP.NET Core metapackages are moved to the core SDK so you can develop libraries and test projects for both ASP.NET Core 2.1 and 2.2 using the ""core"" SDK (provided you use tools 2.2.100+) using version-less package references:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```

In .NET Core / ASP.NET Core 3.0, you will be able to reference the framework via a new mechanism altogether (no web-SDK needed):

```
<ItemGroup>
  <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Is it possible to explicit add the Web Publishing logic to the generic host?

Comment: maybe open an issue on https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore. There are new project types in 3.0 and a new worker Sdk

Comment: `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor` is what i was looking for...many thanks